# Go vet warning on Sprintf

Tags: go

I am working on a project in which I am using something like below

```
func Test(format string, args ...interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)
}
```

Now when I run `go vet -v ./...` it gives me a warning that:

> can't check non-constant format in call to Sprintf

Which I understand, it is because the first argument to `Sprintf` is not a constant and it can be anything which is basically passed as a format string.
It is also fairly common to use, for example [here on vet test itself](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/vet/testdata/print.go#L418)

Now I came to know that it is a bug in vet tool and can be fixed via passing  `-printf=false` argument to the go vet. But this will disable all other `printf` checks also, which I don't want.

Now the real question is, how can I fix these warnings?

Comment: Disregard it. It's not an error, it's a warning, which means it's left up to you to decide if it needs to be fixed or not. In this case, it does not.

Comment: Wait for an update on go vet.

Comment: @Adrian thank you for your suggestion. But it floods the CI build log, and I am looking for a solution to fix this. If there's no possibility, then I have to disregard it

Comment: @icza I heard that it's planned in 1.12, but its flooding my CI logs. Is there any way to fix this for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call 'go vet' through the [`gometalinter`](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter) package, you can tell gometalinter to ignore certain warnings with a [no-lint directive](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter#comment-directives) in a comment.  Example:

```
func Test(format string, args ...interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(format, args...) // nolint: vet
}
```